# What exactly does new object() do in c#

Tags: c#

I have had trouble wrapping my head around this and it seems to have lack luster documentation. 
For example, this code:

`private static readonly Object obj = new Object();`

Can someone parse through this code and explain what is happening here. What exactly are the properties of this new object that was created? Why create an object this way?

Comment: There is actually rather good documentation: **[new operator (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/new-operator)**  first line `Used to create objects and invoke constructors. `

Comment: It is a good reason to send a nastygram to the author of this code, "obj" is a *terrible* variable name.  Something like "lockState" is much more descriptive.  Do beware the rest of the code, if you have the option to not use it then you should take it.

Comment: It is impossible to give meaningful advice re: what that does without more context - how is `obj` used in the rest of your code?

Comment: Ridiculous that this question is upvoted. What is more ridiculous is that the answers are upvoted too.

Answer (score 6):

You create a new oject with the type of `Object`. In most cases a statement like this is used for locking purpuse, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/lock-statement for more information.

Answer (score 4):

It simply creates an object of a type `Object`, which is the base type for all of C# reference types.

I has 4 methods:

- `ToString()`
- `GetHashCode()`
- `GetType()`
- `Equals()`

Every class derives form Object, so it has all of the methods above.

Moreover, 3 of these methods are virtual (so you can override them):

- `ToString()`
- `GetHashCode()`
- `Equals()`

It's sometimes used for locking as Isitar mentioned in his answer.

Comment: does it have any assigned values? is it just an object containing only methods I don't understand how that can be useful

Comment: @MarlonHenderson It has no values assigned. It's not really supposed to be useful. You can do that for language consistency - you can create an instance of any non-abstract type which has a public constructor. Object class meets the requirements.

Answer (score 1):

```
 Object obj
```

that declares a variable of type Object

```
  = new Object();
```

the equals sign is assignment, the new operator creates a reference to a new instance of class Object and the portion of Object() default initializes it.

it will have the default properties of an object.

Comment: ...a new reference to an **instance** of the class...